# How to use head.js to load jQuery correctly?

Tags: jquery, head.js

As my website needs to load a number of scripts (including jQuery), so I decided to use head.js for this purpose. Originally, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js-hotkeys.googlecode.com/files/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

where script.js is my own script. In scripts.js, I was having some code using document ready event like this:

```
$(function() {
//...
});
```

When switching to head.js, I am using this to load the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="head.load.min-1.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
head.load([{jQ: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"},
            {jQHK: "http://js-hotkeys.googlecode.com/files/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js"},
            {BS: "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"},
            {Mine: "scripts.js"}]);
</script>
```

And in scripts.js, I am using:

```
head.ready("jQ", function() {
//...
});
```

My questions are:

1. Am I doing correctly?
2. Can I assume that DOM is always ready when head.ready("jQ",...) is fired (I have experience with my website that sometimes it seems not)?

Comment: why would you even use this technique ?

Comment: It takes time for my website to load a bunch of scripts. What I gave above has been simplified.

Comment: well, the scrips must be at the bottom of the page, and you need to start initializing them at document.ready() which happens for every script that you import from somewhere else anyway, this means that you need to handle your own only. And these scripts do not load on each page refresh, they are cached by the browser, you can check in dev tools in google in the network tab. So i really do believe that this technique is cumbersome. If these are the only scripts you need to load, is nothing compared to what other apps have and it still works great.